# Is the jRails Project something I should use?

Tags: usage, frameworks, ruby-on-rails, jquery

The [jRails](http://github.com/aaronchi/jrails) project is a drop in replacement for the Prototype/scriptalicious helpers already a part of the Rails framework. Are your experiences with this project positive? Does it do what it says on the tin?

Is it still being maintained or is this a bad choice if I want to do jQuery with RoR?

Answer (score 2):

> Is it still being maintained or is this a bad choice if I want to do jQuery with RoR?

Their website doesn't exist anymore, their Google Group has some spam and their code isn't updated.

I guess this isn't maintained anymore and might be a bad choice for continuous development...